# Read only file system errors, especially with discord

Tags: 18.04, permissions, filesystem, snap

Running Ubuntu 18.04

I came across this issue: I was trying to give the discord app a different icon, so in the terminal, I navigated to the discord folder, and eventually to the `discord.desktop` file.

The path: `/snap/discord/109/usr/share/discord/discord.desktop`

(I installed discord from Ubuntu Software)

So, I executed the command:

```
sudo gedit /snap/discord/109/usr/share/discord/discord.desktop
```

And as I expected, up comes the text editor where I can edit the path where discord finds its icon. But, there was a problem: I couldn't write to it for some reason. It said it was a read only file system.

Not being very linux savvy, I tried to do:

```
chmod u+w /snap/discord/109/usr/share/discord/discord.desktop
```

`chmod` (obviously, as I later found out) threw up an error because it was a read only file system)

Now, here is where it gets odd.

I navigated to different directories along that path and executed: `vi temp.txt`

in each one. I get the `error 212: file cannot be opened for writing`, so I think that the whole path is a read only thing. I get that error when I tried to make a `.txt` file using the same command in the `/etc` folder and lots of others as well.

I tried closing and reopening discord, oddly, sometimes there was a `/snap/discord/109` folder, other times there wasn't.
Now, I tried to delete discord using the Ubuntu Software app, but it wouldn't let me, so instead I executed the command:

```
sudo rm -rf /snap/discord
```

but it would not let me, so I was wondering if I had messed something up. I tried booting to a live USB and using fsck to try and fix it, no luck.

So, I tried formatting and reinstalling ubuntu, same issue.

Any ideas, how do I make it not read only?

EDIT: once I reinstalled Ubuntu, I was actually manage to install AND UNINSTALL discord, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Is your entire disk read-only, or just the /snap directory? Do this, open `gedit` and try to create any kind of small text file, and try to save it in your Documents folder. Does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snaps are distributed as read only images. What you're seeing is not a fault; it's the *expected* behavior.

If you do a `mount | grep snap` it will show the snap images currently in use:

```
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-system-monitor_57.snap on /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
```

Note that it says `(ro, nodev...)`. `ro` means read only. Squashfs is a ROM-oriented file system for read only media. Squashfs doesn't really support writing to the image.

The result of this is that you can't edit the content of a snap. This is a security benefit, and in your case a problem.

In your case, adding a new desktop entry, pointing to the snap, housed in your home directory would probably be a good work around. You'd be able to set the icon on the new desktop element.

The other alternative would be to unpack the snap, modify it, and repack it, but this would either disable updates, or be overwritten with each update.